# How to make list element editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find the best way to make a list element editable when it is double clicked.  If I have something set up like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjfqX/3/)

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>World</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('li').dblclick(function() {
   //something here?
});
```

what would be the best way of coding a double click action to let me change the value of the list element clicked?

Comment: There's a library for that called toggle edit. Take a look : http://alz.so/toggleedit/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this uses [contentEditable](http://caniuse.com/contenteditable)

```
$('li').dblclick(function() {
   this.contentEditable=true
   $(this).on('keypress blur', function(e) {
     if(e.keyCode&&e.keyCode==13||e.type=='blur'){
      this.contentEditable=false
      return false
     }
   });
   $(this).focus()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sjfqX/9/

**EDIT**

added focus(). thx @L105

Comment: when we edit and press enter it creates a new div with br tag inside

Comment: yes but goes out if the li. eg. `<li>text<div><br/></div></li>`

Comment: i don't use jQuery ... you don't know how hard this was for me. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In HTML5, you can use `contenteditable`. Bind a click on `window` to remove the attribue.

**EDIT** - I combined some answers and this should do the job :

```
$('li').on({
    dblclick: function() {
        $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true').focus();
    },

    keydown : function(e) {
            if(e.keyCode && e.keyCode === 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).blur();
            }       
     },

    blur: function() {
         $(this).removeAttr('contenteditable');
     }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sjfqX/14/)**

Comment: read the comments in my answer and the problems related to this solution .. it creates <div> elements on ENTER press

Comment: So combine it with mine and add this.focus() after this.contentEditable=true.

Comment: Yes but you need to click a second time on the li to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sjfqX/4/)

```
var $elem = $(this);
var mytext = $elem.text();
$elem.html('<input type="text" class="foo" value="' + mytext + '" />');
```

[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sjfqX/7/)

```
$('li').dblclick(function() {
var $elem = $(this);
var mytext = $elem.text();
$elem.html('<input type="text" class="foo" value="' + mytext + '" /> <span class="save">Save!</span>');
    $(".save").click(function() {
        var mynewtext = $(this).parent().find(".foo").val();
        $elem.html(mynewtext);
    });
});
```

Comment: you have replace it by textbox how about saving value and showing li again ?

Comment: Sort of the same thing, but backward. http://jsfiddle.net/sjfqX/7/ Note that I've replaced #foo with .foo to stop duplicate ids.